# Autofocus not working on samsung device

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using below code for autofocus

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                Arrays.asList(surface, previewReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == cameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                       try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            previewRequestBuilder.set(
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            previewRequestBuilder.set(
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                            captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                                    previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
                        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception! is " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
```

Its working fine with other device but with samsung phones its not working.

Thanks in Advance